# Ember js encode reserved url characters

Tags: ember.js, url-routing

I have query param as array: `?cars=[Audi,Fiat]`
But ember encode it to `?cars=%5BAudi%2CFiat%5D`
How I can get more pretty url like `?cars=[Audi,Fiat]` ?
Why ember encodes reserved url characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `serializeQueryParam` and `deserializeQueryParam` private methods in your route.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.15.1/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L703

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.15.1/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L739

In these methods instead of `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, you can return the value itself and get whatever you want to parse from the string.